# Does $\sigma(n^2)/q \mid q^k n^2$ imply $\sigma(n^2)/q \mid n^2$, if $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$? - Part II

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

(**Preamble:** *This inquiry is an offshoot of this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4197351).*)

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.  Denote the *abundancy index* of $x$ as $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

Recall that an odd perfect number $N = q^k n^2$ is said to be given in *Eulerian form* if $q$ is the special prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Also, elsewhere we showed that
$$\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2)) = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{n^2}{\sigma(q^k)/2}.$$

In the hyperlinked [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4197351), we showed that we have the equation
$$N\cdot\Bigg(I(n^2) - \frac{2(q - 1)}{q}\Bigg) = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q},$$
from which it follows that
$$\frac{N}{\sigma(n^2)/q} = \frac{1}{I(n^2) - \frac{2(q - 1)}{q}} = \frac{q\left(q^{k+1} - 1 \right)}{2(q - 1)} = \frac{q\sigma(q^k)}{2},$$
since
$$I(n^2) = \frac{2}{I(q^k)} = \frac{2q^k (q - 1)}{q^{k+1} - 1}.$$

This shows that the divisibility condition $\sigma(n^2)/q \mid N = q^k n^2$ holds.

Under the assumption $k=1$, since
$$\gcd\left(q,\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}\right) = \gcd\left(q,\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}\right) = \gcd\left(q,\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))\right) = \gcd(\gcd(q,n^2),\sigma(n^2)) = \gcd(1,\sigma(n^2)) = 1,$$
then it follows from $\sigma(n^2)/q \mid q^k n^2$ and $\gcd(q,\sigma(n^2)/q)=1$ that $\sigma(n^2)/q \mid n^2$, which [implies](https://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-23/NNTDM-23-2-012-020.pdf) that $k=1$.

Under the assumption
$$\gcd\left(q,\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}\right) = 1$$
we obtain $\sigma(n^2)/q \mid n^2$, which [implies](https://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-23/NNTDM-23-2-012-020.pdf) that $k=1$.

Hence, we actually have the biconditional
$$\gcd\left(q,\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}\right) = 1 \iff k = 1. \tag{*}$$

Here is my question:

> Is my proof of the biconditional depicted in the section marked with a **(*)** correct?  If not, how can it be mended so as to produce a valid argument?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This answer presents an *alternative proof* for the argument in the original post, and shows that the argument is indeed valid.

---

Taking off from Devansh Singh's preprint in [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/363799063_Gcd_in_Odd_perfect_number/), we have
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q} = \gcd\left(q^{k-1} n^2, \sigma(q^{k-1})\sigma(n^2) - q^{k-1} n^2\right).$$

Therefore,
$$\gcd\left(q,\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}\right) = \gcd\left(q,\gcd\Bigg(q^{k-1} n^2, \sigma(q^{k-1})\sigma(n^2) - q^{k-1} n^2\Bigg)\right).$$

---

Suppose that $k \neq 1$.

It follows that
$$\gcd\left(q,\gcd\Bigg(q^{k-1} n^2, \sigma(q^{k-1})\sigma(n^2) - q^{k-1} n^2\Bigg)\right) = q \geq 5,$$
since $\gcd(q, q^{k-1} n^2) = q$ under the assumption $k \neq 1$, and also $q \mid \sigma(n^2)$ and $q \mid q^{k-1}$.
Hence we have that
$$\gcd\left(q,\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}\right) \neq 1.$$

---

On the other hand, suppose that $k=1$.

It follows that
$$\gcd\left(q,\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q}\right)=\gcd\left(q,\gcd\Bigg(q^{k-1} n^2, \sigma(q^{k-1})\sigma(n^2) - q^{k-1} n^2\Bigg)\right)=\gcd\left(q,\gcd\Bigg(n^2, \sigma(n^2) - n^2\Bigg)\right)=\gcd\left(\gcd(q,n^2),\sigma(n^2) - n^2\right)=\gcd\left(1,\sigma(n^2)-n^2\right)=1.$$

---

**QED**

Comment: To the quick downvoter: Would you mind sharing feedback regarding your vote? As it is, I am totally clueless. Any form of feedback, hopefully constructive, would go a long way towards improving future answers/posts.