# Does the following lower bound improve on $I(q^k) + I(n^2) > 3 - \frac{q-2}{q(q-1)}$, where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number? - Part II

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

**Preamble:  This question is an offshoot of these earlier posts: ([post1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3998982)), ([post2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3067140)).**

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Define the *abundancy index*
$$I(x)=\frac{\sigma(x)}{x}$$
where $\sigma(x)$ is the classical *sum of divisors* of $x$.

Since $q$ is prime, we have the bounds
$$\frac{q+1}{q} \leq I(q^k) < \frac{q}{q-1},$$
which implies, since $N$ is perfect, that
$$\frac{2(q-1)}{q} < I(n^2) = \frac{2}{I(q^k)} \leq \frac{2q}{q+1}.$$

By considering the *negative* product
$$\bigg(I(q^k) - \frac{2(q-1)}{q}\bigg)\bigg(I(n^2) - \frac{2(q-1)}{q}\bigg) < 0,$$
since we obviously have
$$\frac{q}{q-1} < \frac{2(q-1)}{q},$$
then after some routine algebraic manipulations, we arrive at the lower bound
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) > 3 - \frac{q-2}{q(q-1)} = \frac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)}.$$

In ([post2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3067140)), I derived the following inequality:
$$2qn^2 - q\sigma(n^2) < 2n^2 - 1.$$

Using my method, I then get the bounds
$$I(q^k) < \dfrac{q}{q-1} < \dfrac{2(q-1)}{q} + \dfrac{1}{qn^2} < I(n^2)$$
which implies that the product
$$(I(q^k) - x)(I(n^2) - x) < 0$$
is **negative**, where $$x = \dfrac{2(q-1)}{q} + \dfrac{1}{qn^2}.$$  Upon some algebra, I get
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) > \dfrac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)} - \dfrac{q}{(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1)} + \dfrac{1}{qn^2}.$$
But $$- \dfrac{q}{(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1)} + \dfrac{1}{qn^2} = \dfrac{qn^2 (q - 4) + q + 2n^2 - 1}{qn^2 (q - 1)(2n^2 (q - 1) + 1)} > 0,$$
since $q$ is a prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ implies that $q \geq 5$.

So it does appear that the inequality
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) > \dfrac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)} - \dfrac{q}{(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1)} + \dfrac{1}{qn^2}$$
is unconditionally true, which would mean that the new lower bound for $I(q^k) + I(n^2)$ improves on the old.  *Note that we were able to prove this analytically.*

And lastly:  Based on this [answer to a closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3890892/28816), since we appear to have obtained an improved lower bound for $I(q^k) + I(n^2)$, can we then say that there is **indeed** an integer $a$ such that $k \leq a$?

Comment: Note that it is known that $n^2 > {10}^{750}$, by work of [Dris (2012)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html) and [Ochem and Rao (2012)](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2012-81-279/S0025-5718-2012-02563-4/S0025-5718-2012-02563-4.pdf).

Comment: Furthermore, $n^2$ is *bounded*, being a (proper) factor of the (hypothetical) odd perfect number $N=q^k n^2$.

Comment: I also noticed that we actually have the **identity**
$$I(n^2) - \dfrac{2(q-1)}{q} = \dfrac{I(n^2)}{q^{k+1}} = \dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}\cdot\dfrac{1}{qn^2},$$
[per this MO post from January, 2021](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382050).

Comment: I wrote, in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3888565/on-the-quantity-iqk-in2-where-qk-n2-is-an-odd-perfect-number-with/3890892#comment8024507_3890892), "For the fourth, if you get an improved lower bound $g(q)$, then from the above fact, we see that there is only one $k=k_0$ such that $f(k)=g(q)$. Then, we have $k\le \lceil k_0\rceil$". What you have got includes $n$ when $g(q)$ has to be a function only on $q$.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @mathlove!  I do get your point.  But is it not the case that we can interpret $n^2$ to be a *constant* (greater than ${10}^{750}$)?

Comment: It is important to interpret only $q$ to be a constant. If you interpret both $q$ and $n$ to be constants, then $k$ is simply determined by $\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=2q^kn^2$.

Comment: No, I am not interpreting $q$ to be a constant, @mathlove.  Otherwise, $k$ will be constant, and therefore bounded!  =)

Comment: Note that we have
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) = I(q^k) + \dfrac{2}{I(q^k)} = I(n^2) + \dfrac{2}{I(n^2)},$$
and that this sum lies strictly between $57/20$ and $3$.  The first representation is a two-variable representation, the second representation is a single-variable representation.  Since
$$\dfrac{57}{20} < I(n^2) + \dfrac{2}{I(n^2)} < 3,$$
then $n^2$ is a *constant* (greater than ${10}^{750}$).

Comment: I actually meant "$\ldots$ then $n^2$ is *bounded* $\ldots$" in the last line in my previous comment.

Comment: In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3890892/78967), I set $f(k):=I(q^k)+\dfrac{2}{I(q^k)}$ and got $f'(k)$ which mean that I treated $q$ as a constant.

Comment: If $q$ is **indeed** constant, then
$$\dfrac{57}{20}< f(k) < 3$$
can be solved for $k$, which would mean that $k$ is bounded!  =)

Comment: Let $f(k):=I(q^k)+\dfrac{2}{I(q^k)}$ and $g(q,n):=\dfrac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)} - \dfrac{q}{(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1)} + \dfrac{1}{qn^2}$. On second thought, one needs $f(1)-g(q,n)=\dfrac{((q-3)n^2+1)(2n^2-q-1)}{n^2q(q+1)(2n^2(q-1)+1)}\gt  0$, i.e. $2n^2\gt q+1$ under which there exists $K$ satisfying $1\leqslant k\lt K$ and $f(K)=g(q,n)$. But the problem here is that I don't know how to represent $K$ explicitly.

Comment: That is splendid, @mathlove!  Mind sharing your proof for your assertion?  I ask because I know that
$$q + 1 \leq \sigma(q^k) \leq \frac{2n^2}{3} < 2n^2$$
holds in general.  (See [(JIS - Dris (2012))](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html) for the details of the proof.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(k):=I(q^k)+\dfrac{2}{I(q^k)}$ and
$$g(q,n):=\dfrac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)} - \dfrac{q}{(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1)} + \dfrac{1}{qn^2}.$$

One has
$$f'(k)=\frac{-( q^{2 k + 2}- 4 q^{2 k + 1}+2 q^{k + 1}   + 2 q^{2 k} - 1) \log(q)}{(q - 1)q^k (q^{k + 1} - 1)^2}\lt 0$$
so it follows that $f(k)$ is strictly decreasing with
$$\dfrac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)}=\lim_{k\to\infty}f(k)\lt f(k)\le f(1)=\frac{3q^2+2q+1}{q(q+1)}.$$

You have already known that $f(k)\gt g(q,n)\gt \lim_{k\to\infty}f(k)$ and that $f(1)\gt g(q,n)$ which is equivalent to $2n^2\gt q+1$.

It follows that there exists $K$ satisfying $1\leqslant k\lt K$ and $f(K)=g(q,n)$.

Comment: Does $k < K$ follow since the lower bound $g(q,n)$ for $f(k)$ *does not contain* $k$, @mathlove?  =)

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : Yes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the confirmation, @mathlove!  Gladly accepting your answer now!  (A bounty is on your way for your answer to this question, by the way!) =)

Comment: Would you mind checking out this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4214850/28816) please, @mathlove, where I attempt to compute an upper bound for $K$ in terms of $q$ and $n$?  Thank you for your time and attention.

Answer (score 1):

This post complements mathlove's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4214204/28816), and thereby computes an explicit upper bound for $K$ in terms of $q$ and $n$.

---

So here we go:  We require $f(K) = g(q,n)$.

But we have the partial fraction decompositions
$$f(K) = \frac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)} + \frac{2(q - 1)}{q(q^{K+1} - 1)} - \frac{1}{{q^K}(q - 1)}$$
and
$$g(q,n) = \frac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)} - \frac{q}{(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1)} + \frac{1}{qn^2},$$
as computed by WolframAlpha.

Rearranging terms from the equation $f(K) = g(q,n)$ then gives
$$\frac{2(q - 1)}{q(q^{K+1} - 1)} - \frac{1}{qn^2} = \frac{1}{{q^K}(q - 1)} - \frac{q}{(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1)}.$$

After some algebraic simplifications, we obtain
$$\frac{2n^2 (q - 1) - (q^{K+1} - 1)}{qn^2 (q^{K+1} - 1)} = \frac{2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1 - q^{K+1}}{{q^K} (q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1)},$$
from which we finally get
$$\frac{2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1 - q^{K+1}}{qn^2 (q^{K+1} - 1)} = \frac{2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1 - q^{K+1}}{{q^K} (q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1)}.$$

Suppose to the contrary that
$$2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1 - q^{K+1} \neq 0.$$
Then we may cancel $2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1 - q^{K+1}$ in the numerator of both sides of the equation, to get
$${q^K} (q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1) = qn^2 (q^{K+1} - 1).$$
This may be rewritten as
$$2 - \frac{2}{q} + \frac{1}{qn^2} = \frac{2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1}{qn^2} = \frac{q^{K+1} - 1}{q^K (q - 1)}.$$
But we know of the estimates
$$\frac{2(q - 1)}{q} < 2 - \frac{2}{q} + \frac{1}{qn^2} = \frac{q^{K+1} - 1}{q^K (q - 1)} < \frac{q}{q - 1}.$$
These estimates imply that
$$\sqrt{2} < \frac{q}{q - 1},$$
contradicting
$$\frac{q}{q - 1} \leq \frac{5}{4},$$
since $q$ is the special prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ implies that $q \geq 5$.

The contradiction thus obtained means that our assumption that
$$2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1 - q^{K+1} \neq 0$$
is untenable.  This implies that
$$2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1 - q^{K+1} = 0,$$
from which we obtain
$$2n^2 (q - 1) = q^{K+1} - 1$$
$$2n^2 = \frac{q^{K+1} - 1}{q - 1}$$

This implies that
$$q^K < 2n^2$$
$$K \log{q} < \log{2} + 2\log{n}$$
Finally, we get the upper bound
$$K < \log_q{2} + 2\log_q{n}.$$

Comment: Nicely done. I think that you cannot write $\sigma(q^K)=2n^2$ since $K$ is not necessarily an integer.

Comment: Agreed, @mathlove!  I will edit the answer by tomorrow, as I have to sleep by now already.  For the meantime, kindly check out the generalized answer to this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4215891/28816).

Comment: $\sigma(q^K)=2n^2$ does not imply $K \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ since $K$ is not necessarily an integer. In my opinion, writing $\sigma(q^K)$ and $I(q^K)$ is very misleading. More importantly, you don't have to write them to get the result $K < \log_q{2} + 2\log_q{n}$.

Comment: Okay, @mathlove, I will amend this answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This post generalizes this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4214850/28816), since the earlier one is getting too long already.

---

Abbreviate a (strict) lower bound for the quantity
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$$
by $\rho$.

Using my method, we then get the bounds
$$I(q^k) < \dfrac{q}{q-1} < \dfrac{2(q-1)}{q} + \dfrac{\rho}{qn^2} < I(n^2)$$
which implies that the product
$$(I(q^k) - y)(I(n^2) - y) < 0$$
is **negative**, where $$y = \dfrac{2(q-1)}{q} + \dfrac{\rho}{qn^2}.$$  After some careful algebraic simplifications, I get
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) > \frac{2qn^2}{2qn^2 - 2n^2 + \rho} + \frac{2qn^2 - 2n^2 + \rho}{qn^2}$$
which has the partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{2qn^2}{2qn^2 - 2n^2 + \rho} + \frac{2qn^2 - 2n^2 + \rho}{qn^2} = \frac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)} - \frac{\rho q}{(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + \rho)} + \frac{\rho}{qn^2}.$$
Therefore,
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) > \dfrac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)} - \dfrac{\rho q}{(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + \rho)} + \dfrac{\rho}{qn^2}.$$

Since it is known that $\rho > 1$ holds, and that $q \geq 5$, then we also know that
$$-\frac{\rho q}{(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + \rho)} + \frac{\rho}{qn^2} = \frac{\rho \Bigg(qn^2 (q - 4) + \rho(q - 1) + 2n^2\Bigg)}{qn^2 (q - 1)(2n^2 (q - 1) + \rho)} > 0.$$

This means that the new lower bound
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) > h(q,n)$$
where
$$h(q,n) = \frac{2qn^2}{2qn^2 - 2n^2 + \rho} + \frac{2qn^2 - 2n^2 + \rho}{qn^2}$$
improves on the old (and trivial) lower bound
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) > \frac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)}.$$
**Note that $h(q,n)$ does not contain $k$.**

By mathlove's result, we know that there exists a number $K'$ such that $1 \leq k < K'$.

---

We now compute an explicit upper bound for $K'$, in terms of $q$, $n$, and $\rho$.

So here we go:  We require $f(K') = h(q,n)$.

But we have the partial fraction decompositions
$$f(K') = \frac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)} + \frac{2(q - 1)}{q(q^{K' + 1} - 1)} - \frac{1}{q^{K'}(q - 1)}$$
and
$$h(q,n) = \frac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)} - \frac{\rho q}{(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + \rho)} + \frac{\rho}{qn^2}.$$

Equating and rearranging as before, we obtain
$$\frac{2(q - 1)}{q(q^{K' + 1} - 1)} - \frac{\rho}{qn^2} = \frac{1}{q^{K'}(q - 1)} - \frac{\rho q}{(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + \rho)}.$$

After some algebraic simplifications, we get
$$\frac{2n^2 (q - 1) - \rho\bigg(q^{K' + 1} - 1\bigg)}{qn^2 \bigg(q^{K' + 1} - 1\bigg)} = \frac{2n^2 (q - 1) + \rho - \rho q^{K' + 1}}{{q^{K'}}(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + \rho)}.$$

Proceeding similarly as in the other [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4214850/28816), suppose to the contrary that
$$2n^2 (q - 1) - \rho\bigg(q^{K' + 1} - 1\bigg) \neq 0.$$

Then we can cancel the numerator of both sides of the equation, since
$$2n^2 (q - 1) - \rho\bigg(q^{K' + 1} - 1\bigg) = 2n^2 (q - 1) + \rho - \rho q^{K' + 1}.$$

We thus obtain
$$qn^2 \bigg(q^{K' + 1} - 1\bigg) = {q^{K'}}(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + \rho)$$
which can be rewritten as
$$\frac{q^{K' + 1} - 1}{{q^{K'}}(q - 1)} = \frac{2qn^2 - 2n^2 + \rho}{qn^2}.$$

But, as before, we have the estimates
$$\frac{2(q - 1)}{q} < \frac{2qn^2 - 2n^2 + \rho}{qn^2}$$
(since $\rho$ is positive), and
$$\frac{q^{K' + 1} - 1}{{q^{K'}}(q - 1)} < \frac{q}{q - 1},$$
which (again) implies that
$$\sqrt{2} < \frac{q}{q - 1},$$
contradicting
$$\frac{q}{q - 1} \leq \frac{5}{4}$$
since $q$ is the special prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ implies that $q \geq 5$.

The contradiction thus obtained means that our assumption that
$$2n^2 (q - 1) - \rho\bigg(q^{K' + 1} - 1\bigg) \neq 0$$
is untenable.  This implies that
$$\frac{2n^2}{\rho} = \frac{q^{K' + 1} - 1}{q - 1}.$$

---

We finally obtain the inequality
$$q^{K'} < \frac{2n^2}{\rho}$$
which implies that
$$K' < \log_q {2} + 2\log_q {n} - \log_q {\rho}.$$

**MINOR CAVEAT:** As correctly pointed out by mathlove, $K'$ (and therefore also $K$ in the other answer) may not be an integer.  Hence, we may not write $\sigma(q^{K'})$ or $I(q^{K'})$ (nor $\sigma(q^K)$ and $I(q^{K})$ in the other answer).

---

Per this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4028814/28816) to a tangentially related question, the best currently known lower bound for $\sigma(n^2)/q^k$ is
$$\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} \geq {3^3} \times {5^3} = 3375.$$

Comment: Note that we may take $\rho > 3374$.