# Proof-verification request: If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then $q < n^{2/5}$.

Tags: solution-verification, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Hereinafter, we will denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Let $q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  We wish to show that $q < n^{2/5}$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

Suppose to the contrary that $n^{2/5} \leq q$.  Note that $n^{2/5} \neq q$ because otherwise we obtain $n^2 = q^5$ which contradicts $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  Hence, by assumption, we have
$$n < q^{5/2}.$$

Since $q^k < n^2$ [(JIS - Dris, 2012)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html), then note that this implies that
$$q^k < n^2 < q^5$$
$$k < 5,$$
which forces $k=1$ since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

However, from this [answer to a closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4215891/28816), we have the inequality
$$1 = k < K < \frac{\log 2}{\log q} + 2\log_q {n} - \frac{\log \rho}{\log q}, \tag{1}$$
where the quantity $\rho$ satisfies
$$\rho < \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)} = \gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2))$$
(Note that we may take $\rho > 3374$ by this [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4197182/does-the-following-lower-bound-improve-on-iqk-in2-3-fracq-2qq/4215891#comment9467934_4215891).)

We then get the estimate
$$1 < K < \frac{\log 2}{\log q} + 2\log_q {n} - \frac{\log \rho}{\log q} < \frac{\log 2}{\log 5} + 2\log_q {q^{5/2}} - \frac{\log 3374}{\log 5}$$ $$= 5 + \frac{\log 2}{\log 5} - \frac{\log 3374}{\log 5} = \log_5\bigg(\frac{3125}{1687}\bigg) \approx 0.3830421, \tag{2}$$
which is a contradiction.  Hence, we conclude that $q < n^{2/5}$.

Here are my:

> **QUESTIONS:** Is this argument logically sound?  (In particular, are the estimates in Steps **(1)** and **(2)** correct?)  If not, how can it be mended so as to produce a valid proof?

---

**Added from this [recent comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4216490/proof-verification-request-if-qk-n2-is-an-odd-perfect-number-with-special-p?noredirect=1#comment9807439_4216490)**: Just in case it is not clear - Another way to arrive at the contradiction in Estimate $(2)$ is as follows:
$$K \log q < \log 2 + 2 \log n - \log \rho < \log 2 + 2 \log q^{5/2} - \log 3374$$
$$= \log 2 + 5 \log q - \log 3374 \implies (K - 5) \log q < \log 2 - \log 3374$$
$$\implies (K - 5) \log 5 \leq (K - 5) \log q < \log 2 - \log 3374 \implies K - 5 < \frac{\log 2 - \log 3374}{\log 5}$$
$$\implies K < 5 + \log_{5} 2 - \log_{5} 3374 = \log_{5} \left(\frac{3125}{1687}\right) \approx 0.3830421.$$

(Note that I am using the fact that the logarithm is a *monotonically increasing function*.)

Comment: Just in case it is not clear - Another way to arrive at the contradiction in Estimate $(2)$ is as follows:
$$K \log q < \log 2 + 2 \log n - \log \rho < \log 2 + 2 \log q^{5/2} - \log 3374 = \log 2 + 5 \log q - \log 3374$$ 
$$\iff (K - 5)\log q < \log 2 - \log 3374 \implies (K - 5)\log 5 \leq (K - 5)\log q < \log 2 - \log 3374$$ 
$$\implies K - 5 < \frac{\log 2 - \log 3374}{\log 5} \implies K < 5 + \log_5 {2} - \log_5 {3374} = \log_5\left(\frac{3125}{1687}\right) \approx 0.3830421.$$  **QED**

Comment: In the inequality $\dfrac{\log 2}{\log q} + 2\log_q {n} - \dfrac{\log \rho}{\log q} < \dfrac{\log 2}{\log 5} + 2\log_q {q^{5/2}} - \dfrac{\log 3374}{\log 5}$, it seems that you used $- \dfrac{\log \rho}{\log q} < - \dfrac{\log 3374}{\log 5}$, but this does not hold for $\rho=3375$ and $q=13$.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @mathlove!  Please refer to my [comment above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4216490/proof-verification-request-if-qk-n2-is-an-odd-perfect-number-with-special-p?noredirect=1#comment9807439_4216490) for an alternative point of view.  (Note that I am using the fact that $\log x$ is a *monotonically increasing function* of $x$.)

Comment: In the inequality $(K−5)\log 5\leqslant (K−5)\log q$, you are assuming that $K-5\geqslant 0$. So, I think that what you've done is "Supposing that $n^{2/5}\leqslant q$ and $K\geqslant 5$ gives a contradiction".

Comment: I do not need to make the assumption $K \geq 5$, @mathlove.

Comment: If you don't assume $K\geqslant 5$, then the inequality $(K−5)\log 5\leqslant (K−5)\log q$ does not hold for $K=2$ and $q=13$.

Comment: Hmm. I know that $1 = k < K$ (under the given assumption), and that $K$ "behaves" like $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  This may be taken to "imply" that $K \geq 5$ holds.

Comment: Let $F(q):=\dfrac{\log 2 + 5 \log q - \log 3374}{\log q}$. Since $F'(q)>0$, we have $K <F(q) \lt \displaystyle\lim_{q\to\infty}F(q)=5$. So, $(K - 5) \log 5 \leqslant (K - 5) \log q$ does not hold.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, @mathlove!  Please write out your comments into a full answer, so that I may be able to upvote and then accept.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$1 < K < \frac{\log 2}{\log q} + 2\log_q {n} - \frac{\log \rho}{\log q} < \frac{\log 2}{\log 5} + 2\log_q {q^{5/2}} - \frac{\log 3374}{\log 5}$$

It seems that you used $- \dfrac{\log \rho}{\log q} < - \dfrac{\log 3374}{\log 5}$, but this does not hold for $\rho=3375$ and $q=13$.

---

> $$K \log q < \log 2 + 2 \log n - \log \rho < \log 2 + 2 \log q^{5/2} - \log 3374$$
> $$= \log 2 + 5 \log q - \log 3374 \implies (K - 5) \log q < \log 2 - \log 3374$$
> $$\implies (K - 5) \log 5 \leq (K - 5) \log q < \log 2 - \log 3374 $$

Let $F(q):=\dfrac{\log 2+5\log q−\log{3374}}{\log q}$.

Since $F′(q)>0$, we have $K<F(q)<\displaystyle\lim_{q\to\infty}F(q)=5$.

So, $(K−5)\log 5\leqslant (K−5)\log q$ does not hold.