# On the inequality $I(q^k)+I(n^2) \leq \frac{3q^{2k} + 2q^k + 1}{q^k (q^k + 1)}$ where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

(**Note: This post is an offshoot of this [earlier MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4197182).**)

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Define the *abundancy index*
$$I(x)=\frac{\sigma(x)}{x}$$
where $\sigma(x)$ is the classical *sum of divisors* of $x$.

Since $q$ is prime, we have the bounds
$$1 < \frac{q+1}{q} \leq I(q^k) < \frac{q}{q-1} \leq \frac{5}{4},$$
which implies, since $N$ is perfect, that
$$\frac{8}{5} \leq \frac{2(q-1)}{q} < I(n^2) = \frac{2}{I(q^k)} \leq \frac{2q}{q+1} < 2.$$

By considering the *nonnegative* product
$$\bigg(I(q^k) - \frac{q+1}{q}\bigg)\bigg(I(n^2) - \frac{q+1}{q}\bigg) \geq 0,$$
then after some routine algebraic manipulations, we arrive at the upper bound
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) \leq 3 - \Bigg(\frac{q-1}{q(q+1)}\Bigg) = \frac{3q^2 + 2q + 1}{q(q + 1)}.$$

Here, I shall derive the following *slightly* different bound:

> If $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then
> $$I(q^k) + I(n^2) \leq \frac{3q^{2k} + 2q^k + 1}{q^k (q^k + 1)}.$$

> **PROOF:** Suppose that $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$.  Then we have
> $$\sigma(q^k) \geq q^k + 1$$
> so that
> $$\frac{1}{4} \geq \frac{1}{q-1} > I(q^k) - 1 \geq \frac{1}{q^k}$$
> and
> $$1 > \frac{q-1}{q+1} \geq I(n^2) - 1 > \frac{q-2}{q} \geq \frac{3}{5}$$
> so that we obtain
> $$\Bigg(\bigg(I(q^k) - 1\bigg) - \frac{1}{q^k}\Bigg)\Bigg(\bigg(I(n^2) - 1\bigg) - \frac{1}{q^k}\Bigg)$$
> is *nonnegative*.
> Thus, we have
> $$\Bigg(\bigg(I(q^k) - 1\bigg) - \frac{1}{q^k}\Bigg)\Bigg(\bigg(I(n^2) - 1\bigg) - \frac{1}{q^k}\Bigg) \geq 0$$
> which is **equivalent** to
> $$\bigg(I(q^k) - 1\bigg)\bigg(I(n^2) - 1\bigg) + \frac{1}{q^{2k}} \geq \frac{1}{q^k}\Bigg(I(q^k) + I(n^2) - 2\Bigg)$$
> $$\Bigg(3 - \bigg(I(q^k) + I(n^2)\bigg)\Bigg) + \frac{1}{q^{2k}} \geq \frac{1}{q^k}\Bigg(I(q^k) + I(n^2) - 3\Bigg) + \frac{1}{q^k}$$
> $$\Bigg(\frac{q^k + 1}{q^k}\Bigg)\Bigg(3 - \bigg(I(q^k) + I(n^2)\bigg)\Bigg) = \Bigg(1 + \frac{1}{q^k}\Bigg)\Bigg(3 - \bigg(I(q^k) + I(n^2)\bigg)\Bigg) \geq \frac{1}{q^k} - \frac{1}{q^{2k}} = \frac{q^k - 1}{q^{2k}}$$
> $$3 - \bigg(I(q^k) + I(n^2)\bigg) \geq \frac{q^k - 1}{q^k (q^k + 1)}.$$
> Hence, we finally get
> $$I(q^k) + I(n^2) \leq 3 - \Bigg(\frac{q^k - 1}{q^k (q^k + 1)}\Bigg) = \frac{3q^{2k} + 2q^k + 1}{q^k (q^k + 1)}.$$
> **QED.**

Notice the **striking similarity** between the upper bound
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) \leq 3 - \Bigg(\frac{q-1}{q(q+1)}\Bigg) = \frac{3q^2 + 2q + 1}{q(q + 1)},$$
and the upper bound
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) \leq 3 - \Bigg(\frac{q^k - 1}{q^k (q^k + 1)}\Bigg) = \frac{3q^{2k} + 2q^k + 1}{q^k (q^k + 1)}.$$

Here are my:

> **QUESTIONS:**

> **(1)** Does this argument imply that $k=1$?  (i.e. in the sense that $k$ is taken to be a **placeholder** for $1$?)

> **(2)** Similar to the train of thought in this post, can you think of a way to show that
> $$I(q^k) + I(n^2) > 3 - \Bigg(\frac{q^k - 2}{q^k (q^k - 1)}\Bigg) = \frac{3q^{2k} - 4q^k + 2}{q^k (q^k - 1)}?$$

> **(3)** If it is *not possible* to prove the inequality in **(2)**, can you explain why?

Comment: I think that the answer to the question (1) is no. Let $f(k):=\dfrac{3q^{2k} + 2q^k + 1}{q^k (q^k + 1)}$. It follows from $I(q^k)+I(n^2)\leqslant f(1)$ that $I(q^k)+I(n^2)\leqslant f(k)$ since $f'(k)$ is positive.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @mathlove. Do you have some comments regarding my other questions?

Comment: I don't know how to prove the inequality in (2). Let $g(k):=\dfrac{3q^{2k} -4q^k + 2}{q^k (q^k -1)}$. Then, since $g'(k)$ is positive, one gets $g(1)\leqslant g(k)$. So, it does *not* follow from $I(q^k)+I(n^2)\gt g(1)$ that $I(q^k)+I(n^2)\gt g(k)$. This does not mean that it is not possible to prove $I(q^k)+I(n^2)\gt g(k)$.

Comment: If you would write out your last two comments as an answer, I'd be more than willing to upvote then accept it, @mathlove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the answer to the question (1) is no. Let $f(k):=\dfrac{3q^{2k}+2q^k+1}{q^k(q^k+1)}$. It follows from $I(q^k)+I(n^2)\leqslant f(1)$ that $I(q^k)+I(n^2)\leqslant f(k)$ since $f′(k)$ is positive.

---

I don't know how to prove the inequality in (2). Let $g(k):=\dfrac{3q^{2k} -4q^k + 2}{q^k (q^k -1)}$. Then, since $g'(k)$ is positive, one gets $g(1)\leqslant g(k)$. So, it does *not* follow from $I(q^k)+I(n^2)\gt g(1)$ that $I(q^k)+I(n^2)\gt g(k)$. This does not mean that it is not possible to prove $I(q^k)+I(n^2)\gt g(k)$.