# Does the following lower bound improve on $I(q^k)+I(n^2) > \frac{57}{20}$, where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number?

Tags: solution-verification, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

**Preamble:** This question is an offshoot of this earlier [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4197182).  (This inquiry has likewise been cross-posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424411) last June $10, 2022$.)

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Define the *abundancy index*
$$I(x)=\frac{\sigma(x)}{x}$$
where $\sigma(x)$ is the classical *sum of divisors* of $x$.

Since $q$ is prime, we have the bounds
$$\frac{q+1}{q} \leq I(q^k) < \frac{q}{q-1},$$
which implies, since $N$ is perfect, that
$$\frac{2(q-1)}{q} < I(n^2) = \frac{2}{I(q^k)} \leq \frac{2q}{q+1}.$$

By considering the *negative* product
$$\bigg(I(q^k) - \frac{2(q-1)}{q}\bigg)\bigg(I(n^2) - \frac{2(q-1)}{q}\bigg) < 0,$$
since we obviously have
$$\frac{q}{q-1} < \frac{2(q-1)}{q},$$
then after some routine algebraic manipulations, we arrive at the lower bound
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) > 3 - \frac{q-2}{q(q-1)} = \frac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)}.$$

Note that, since $q$ is a prime satisfying $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $q \geq 5$, so that
$$f(q) = \frac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)}$$
is **increasing**, since
$$f'(q) = \frac{q(q - 4) + 2}{\bigg(q(q - 1)\bigg)^2} > 0.$$
This means that
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) > f(q) \geq f(5) = \frac{57}{20}.$$

By this [answer to a closely related MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/404066/10365), we have the improved bounds:
$$I(q^k) < \frac{q}{q - 1} < \frac{2(q - 1)}{q} + \frac{1}{qn^2} < I(n^2).$$

Using my method, this implies that the product
$$(I(q^k) - y)(I(n^2) - y) < 0$$
is **negative**, where $$y = \dfrac{2(q-1)}{q} + \dfrac{1}{qn^2}.$$  After some algebraic simplifications, we get
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) > \dfrac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)} - \dfrac{q}{(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1)} + \dfrac{1}{qn^2}.$$
But $$- \dfrac{q}{(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1)} + \dfrac{1}{qn^2} = \dfrac{qn^2 (q - 4) + q + 2n^2 - 1}{qn^2 (q - 1)(2n^2 (q - 1) + 1)} > 0,$$
since $q \geq 5$.

So the inequality
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) > \dfrac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)} - \dfrac{q}{(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1)} + \dfrac{1}{qn^2} = g_1(q,n)$$
is unconditionally true, which would mean that the new lower bound $g_1(q,n)$ for $I(q^k) + I(n^2)$ improves on the old $f(q)$.  *Note that we were able to prove this analytically.*

---

Now consider the expression
$$g_1(q,n) - \frac{57}{20} = \Bigg(\dfrac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)} - \frac{57}{20}\Bigg) - \dfrac{q}{(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1)} + \dfrac{1}{qn^2} = a_1 + a_2,$$
where
$$a_1 = \dfrac{3q^2 - 4q + 2}{q(q - 1)} - \frac{57}{20} \geq 0$$
(by our previous considerations), and
$$a_2 = - \dfrac{q}{(q - 1)(2qn^2 - 2n^2 + 1)} + \dfrac{1}{qn^2} = \dfrac{qn^2 (q - 4) + q + 2n^2 - 1}{qn^2 (q - 1)(2n^2 (q - 1) + 1)} > 0.$$

We therefore conclude that
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) > g_1(q,n) > \frac{57}{20},$$
so that *we do appear to have gotten an improved lower bound for $I(q^k) + I(n^2)$*, **better than** $57/20$.

---

By [Lemma II.2, page 1 of this conference paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.1548.pdf), "any further improvement to the lower bound of $57/20$ for $I(q^k) + I(n^2)$ would be equivalent to showing that there are no odd perfect numbers of the form $5n^2$, which would be a very major result".

---

Here are my:

**QUESTIONS**

> **(1)** Is this proof correct?

> **(2)** If the answer to *Question* **(1)** is **NO**, can the proof be mended so as to produce a logically valid argument?